# How to rename in ascending order of files in a folder

Tags: for-loop, rename

I have a folder named `FOLDER` and inside, I have files named

```
file.2.fna
file.5.fna
file.6.fna
file.8.fna
file.12.fna
```

I want to rename the number part of each file in an ascending order starting with 0.
The desired output is

```
file.0.fna
file.1.fna
file.2.fna
file.3.fna
file.4.fna
```

I can do this manually by

```
mv FOLDER/file.2.fna FOLDER/file.0.fna
rm FOLDER/file.2.fna
```

But it does not seem appropriate since I have several dozens of files
Is there a for loop to do the job?

The for loop I've tried is

```
for file in FOLDER/file.*.fna; do n=0; mv file FOLDER/file.${file}.fna      
FOLDER/file.$n.fna; n=$n+1 ; done
```

This results in only single file with index 0.
I'm not sure how to increase n by 1 here.

Thank you

Comment: I would start by looking at `ls -1` which sorts your files alphabetically. You could then write a loop to rename your ordered files as you wish.

Comment: Hi @Bishal, I inserted the for loop code I've tried. Still have some problems.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have got around this by

```
#!/bin/bash

a=0
echo $a
for i in file_*; do
new=$(printf "file_%d" "$a")
echo $new
mv -i -- "$i" "$new"
let a=a+1
done
```